# Right side click on track pad issue

Tags: macbook-pro, trackpad

I am facing a strange issue with my track pad. My machine is a MacBook Pro Retina Display (Mid 2012) updated with Yosemite.
So when i click on the track pad's right side, the track pad clicked down properly but nothing happens, although the left side is working properly.

Answer (score 1):

What if you click while holding two fingers on the track pad?

If that works then it might just be the setting: from System Preferences, Trackpad, you're looking for the setting pictured in the following screenshot.

[image: trackpad right click]

(Screenshot courtesy of wikihow.com)